# Combine different p.d.f. of the same random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I have a random variable $X$, which I know the historical distribution (for 10 years I recorded this variable and I'm quite sure it follows this distribution) $f_h(X)$ that could be a Gaussian, Weibull or exponential.
Then i have another distribution $f_f(X)$ that indicate a future forecast for this variable. I'm quite bad in statistic but i was thinking to:

- Use a convex combination where $f(X)=0.5*f_h(X)+0.5*f_f(X)$ with maybe different weight, in the picture is the "combined 1".
- Make a Joint probability distribution $f(h,f) = f_h(X) \cdot
     f_f(X)$  assuming that they are independent variables, in the
  pictures is the "combined 2" (here i had to divide the p.d.f. by the area under the curve to have a CDF=1)

[Example pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keBqH.png)

thanks!

Comment: Where does the forecast $f_f$ come from?

Comment: basically they are meteorological data (temperature, wind speed) for a specific site, in 10 year for example the wind sped follows the Weibull distribution. i have then the forecasting that has an uncertainty modeled with a normal distribution

Comment: Sounds like your forecast already contains the information from $f_h$, doesn't it? Why do you feel the need to manually convex-combine the two? The forecast should be by definition your best model for $f$ from now on.

Comment: because i have only the mean value and std for the forecast, if i have a forecast that indicated me 25 using only the forecast pdf I'll consider also higher value that i never had in the past.